# Track or show the history of logins to Facebook from a particular device

Tags: facebook

Someone else's email address came up in the login part of Facebook when I went to log in using my iPad.

I want to know when they last logged on from this device because they shouldn't have been on my iPad.

Is there any way of tracking this history?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to know when the other person logged onto Facebook.

It should be there in your browser history on Safari on your iPad (unless he/she deleted history, which I doubt he/she did).

Note: You cannot view last logins into another account via your Facebook account.

Comment: What if it was more than a month ago? Which it may have been